# Only allow the user to select a maximum of three blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a piece of code that adds an event listener to a number of buttons, when the user clicks a button a class is applied to the button container. How can I restrict this so the user can only select a maximum of three buttons. The code below is working to a point, when you get to three you cannot deselect. Can anyone help me achieve

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var total = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (total < 3 && blocks[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      blocks[i].classList.remove("active");
      total--;
    } else if (total < 3 && !blocks[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      blocks[i].classList.add("active");
      total++;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.block{
  padding: 50px;
  border:1px solid;
  max-width:
}
.block.active{
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

this.

Comment: Both of your branches are predicated on `total < 3 &&`, which is never true once you have three items selected.

Comment: all you need is to use this: `total <= 3 &&...` on your first `if` statement, instead of just a `=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to remove this condition `total < 3 &&` from your first `if`. The number of selected items is irrelevant if the element is already selected. You just want to de-select it.

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var total = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (blocks[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      blocks[i].classList.remove("active");
      total--;
    } else if (total < 3 && !blocks[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      blocks[i].classList.add("active");
      total++;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.block{
  padding: 50px;
  border:1px solid;
  max-width:
}
.block.active{
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```